# Installing ruby with rvm fails on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, curl, proxy, rvm

I have been trying to install ruby 1.9.2 using rvm but I'm unable to get it to work..

I am behind a proxy, but I have configured both http_proxy and https_proxy.

**Output:**

```
ta@ci:~$ rvm install 1.9.2-p136
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/ta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 407
ERROR: The requested url does not exist: 'https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.bz2'
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 407
ERROR: There was an error, please check /home/ta/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Have you read this? : http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/proxy/

Comment: @rdvdijk yes but the proxy requires authentication and there is no such example in beginrescueend.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I managed to get it to work this way as well. Using the .curlrc is also a good idea, but I don't like storing my password as plain text on the machine.

rvm install 1.9.2-p136 --proxy http://username:password@domain:port

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put these lines in your `~/.curlrc` file:

```
proxy-user = "username:password"
proxy = "http://proxy.domain.com:8080"
```

I got this from the `curl` manual page, which can be found [online here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Quote:

> .. The config file is a text file in which command line arguments can be written which then will be used as if they were written on the actual command line. ..
>
> .. Long option names can optionally be given in the config file without the initial double dashes. ..

Comment: Thanks @rdvdijk. Eventually I managed to get it to work, but this is also handy to know. Thanks for your help